# How to insert template tag inside another template Vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, components

I'm trying to make a component that has a slot with a name attribute and another component with the same structure. So, I want to put the second component inside the first but in another outside component.

Example:

App.vue

```
<template>
    <ComponentA>
        <ComponentB>Hello World!</ComponentB>
    </ComponentA>
</template>
```

ComponentA.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="A">
        <slot name="a1"></slot>
        <slot name="a2"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

ComponentB.vue

```
<template slot="a2">
    <div id="B">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

**UPDATE!**

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/v6q35wn0xy)

If I write

```
<slot></slot>
```

instead of

```
 <slot name='a2'></slot>
```

in ComponentA it will work. But I need use the last form, because I must control the order.

Comment: I didn't quite get the question. I bet the answer is easy because the slots and components together are usually mind-boggling but easy. Could you explain a bit more to help us help you?

Comment: Sadly, this question is not clear. Also, it would be good to explain what problem you're facing and provide a fiddle or pen where we can reproduce the issue. Could you please read again what you wrote and reformulate the question so we can help you?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

The problem is when I run the program, Hello World! is not displayed on the screen. But if I write <slot></slot> instead of <slot name="a2"></slot> the phrase appears.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code online:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/v6q35wn0xy)